# Too Long Query Duration in SQL Server 2008 R2 DataCenter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have a query and [this is an actual execution plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vq0ka.png)

[image]
As you can see  - Clustered Index Seek takes 99%.
Also it seeks on primary keys (type **int**).

Table *Source* has 275 000 rows.
Table *AuthorSource* has 2 275 000 rows.

No partition and compression used.

The problem is that first time execution takes 25-40 seconds. But the second run successively takes 1-2 seconds.

Also we have replication, queue reader, log reader agents running on this server.
Amount of RAM: 4GB
Sql Server uses: 3.7GB

We think, that sql caches query after first execution for some period of time, and this is the reason, that second run takes only 1-2 seconds.

But irrespective of cache and other reasons, it is very strange, that primary key index seek query takes 20-40 seconds.

**This issue is repeated. Any different parameters** we provide to the query  - we get same results: very long first time query and fast the second and the following.

May be some additional settings or Resource Governor ability we have to use ?

```
        exec sp_executesql N'
SELECT [Project1].[C1] AS         [C1]
FROM   ( SELECT CAST(1 AS bit) AS X
       ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
              (SELECT [GroupBy1].[A1] AS                        [C1]
              FROM    ( SELECT COUNT(CAST(1 AS bit)) AS         [A1]
                      FROM    (SELECT [Extent1].[Mention_ID]                       AS [Mention_ID]                      ,
                                      [Extent1].[Theme_ID]                         AS [Theme_ID]                        ,
                                      [Extent1].[Mention_Weight]                   AS [Mention_Weight]                  ,
                                      [Extent1].[AuthorSource_ID]                  AS [AuthorSource_ID1]                ,
                                      [Extent1].[Mention_CreationDate]             AS [Mention_CreationDate]            ,
                                      [Extent1].[Mention_DeletedMark]              AS [Mention_DeletedMark]             ,
                                      [Extent1].[Mention_AuthorTags]               AS [Mention_AuthorTags]              ,
                                      [Extent1].[Mention_Tonality]                 AS [Mention_Tonality]                ,
                                      [Extent1].[Mention_Comment]                  AS [Mention_Comment]                 ,
                                      [Extent1].[Mention_AdditionDate]             AS [Mention_AdditionDate]            ,
                                      [Extent1].[UserToAnswer_ID]                  AS [UserToAnswer_ID]                 ,
                                      [Extent1].[GeoName_ID]                       AS [GeoName_ID]                      ,
                                      [Extent1].[Geo_ID]                           AS [Geo_ID]                          ,
                                      [Extent1].[Mention_PermaLinkHash]            AS [Mention_PermaLinkHash]           ,
                                      [Extent1].[Mention_IsFiltredByAuthor]        AS [Mention_IsFiltredByAuthor]       ,
                                      [Extent1].[Mention_IsFiltredByGeo]           AS [Mention_IsFiltredByGeo]          ,
                                      [Extent1].[Mention_IsFiltredBySource]        AS [Mention_IsFiltredBySource]       ,
                                      [Extent1].[Mention_IsFiltredBySourceType]    AS [Mention_IsFiltredBySourceType]   ,
                                      [Extent1].[GengineLog_InstanceId]            AS [GengineLog_InstanceId]           ,
                                      [Extent1].[Mention_PermaLinkBinaryHash]      AS [Mention_PermaLinkBinaryHash]     ,
                                      [Extent1].[Mention_APIType]                  AS [Mention_APIType]                 ,
                                      [Extent1].[Mention_IsFilteredByAuthorSource] AS [Mention_IsFilteredByAuthorSource],
                                      [Extent1].[Mention_IsFavorite]               AS [Mention_IsFavorite]              ,
                                      [Extent1].[Mention_SpamType]                 AS [Mention_SpamType]                ,
                                      [Extent1].[MentionContent_ID]                AS [MentionContent_ID]               ,
                                      [Extent2].[AuthorSource_ID]                  AS [AuthorSource_ID2]                ,
                                      [Extent2].[Author_ID]                        AS [Author_ID]                       ,
                                      [Extent2].[Source_ID]                        AS [Source_ID]                       ,
                                      [Extent2].[Author_Nick]                      AS [Author_Nick]                     ,
                                      [Extent2].[Author_UrlBinaryHash]             AS [Author_UrlBinaryHash]            ,
                                      [Extent2].[AuthorSource_Type]                AS [AuthorSource_Type]               ,
                                      [Extent2].[Author_Url]                       AS [Author_Url]                      ,
                                      [Extent2].[AuthorSource_Description]         AS [AuthorSource_Description]        ,
                                      [Extent2].[AuthorSource_Gender]              AS [AuthorSource_Gender]
                              FROM    [dbo].[Mention]                              AS [Extent1]
                                      LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AuthorSource]         AS [Extent2]
                                      ON      [Extent1].[AuthorSource_ID] = [Extent2].[AuthorSource_ID]
                              WHERE   (
                                              [Extent1].[Mention_DeletedMark] <> CAST(1 AS bit)
                                      )
                              AND
                                      (
                                              [Extent1].[Mention_IsFiltredByAuthor] <> CAST(1 AS bit)
                                      )
                              AND
                                      (
                                              [Extent1].[Mention_IsFilteredByAuthorSource] <> CAST(1 AS bit)
                                      )
                              AND
                                      (
                                              [Extent1].[Mention_IsFiltredByGeo] <> CAST(1 AS bit)
                                      )
                              AND
                                      (
                                              [Extent1].[Mention_IsFiltredBySource] <> CAST(1 AS bit)
                                      )
                              AND
                                      (
                                              [Extent1].[Mention_IsFiltredBySourceType] <> CAST(1 AS bit)
                                      )
                              )                              AS [Filter1]
                              LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Source] AS [Extent3]
                              ON      [Filter1].[Source_ID] = [Extent3].[Source_ID]
                      WHERE   (
                                      [Filter1].[Theme_ID] = @p__linq__49557
                              )
                      AND
                              (
                                      [Extent3].[Source_Type] <> @p__linq__49558
                              )
                      ) AS [GroupaBy1]
              ) AS [Project1]
       ON     1 = 1
',N'@p__linq__49557 int,@p__linq__49558 int',@p__linq__49557=7966,@p__linq__49558=8
```

[IndexSeeking Performance Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hn2VL.png)

Also we wrote query manually in sql with this simple code:

```
        Select COUNT(1) from Mention m inner join AuthorSource auth on m.AuthorSource_ID = auth.AuthorSource_ID inner join
    Source s on auth.Source_ID = s.Source_ID where 
    m.Mention_DeletedMark = 0 AND m.Mention_IsFilteredByAuthorSource = 0 AND m.Mention_IsFiltredByAuthor = 0 
    AND m.Mention_IsFiltredByGeo = 0 AND m.Mention_IsFiltredBySource = 0 AND m.Mention_IsFiltredBySourceType = 0
    AND m.Theme_ID = 7966
    and s.Source_Type <> 8
```

and execution plan is the same that we posted.

Comment: Please post the query as well.

Comment: Can you change all the `<> CAST(1 AS bit)` to `= CAST(0 AS bit)` without changing the semantics of the query? Are these columns nullable?

Comment: there are no inner joins in your SQL (only Left joins), unlike execution plan, is it normal?(sorry for offtop)

Comment: This is a query that generated by linq to entities. We can change only linq query.

Comment: we see that actual execution plan for this query is ideal. So we think that problem is not in query.

Comment: @mmcteam.com.ua - True you are getting seeks. Not sure that nested loops is the best join strategy though for this number of rows. The most likely explanation for your performance observations is that the first time it runs it needs to do a lot of physical i/o and on subsequent executions the pages are in the buffer cache. Can you try with `SET STATISTICS IO ON` and `SET STATISTICS TIME ON`?

Comment: Table 'Source'. Scan count 0, logical reads 14110, physical reads 154, read-ahead reads 944, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'AuthorSource'. Scan count 0, logical reads 18962, physical reads 30, read-ahead reads 14976, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Mention'. Scan count 1, logical reads 28, physical reads 3, read-ahead reads 25, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.


 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 47 ms,  elapsed time = 15199 ms.

Comment: @Martin - You wrote that nested loops was not the best strategy. What do you can suggest ? Can you change our query at the end of our post?

Comment: The logical reads are not actually that high (about 260 MB) Maybe it's the random I/O from the index seeks that is the killer. It might be worth trying a hash join to see if that performs any better or worse.

Comment: @Martin, you see that we wrote in question, that this issue is repeated. So if it is random I/O or smth. else - it is very strange that issue occurs only query first runs. And not affect other runs. But first run of the query is very slow in 90% of cases.

Comment: @mmcteam-com-ua but after the first run the pages will be in the buffer cache and so retrieved from memory not disc.

Comment: @Martin - but the question is still actual: some random I/O occurs each first query run ? (Also changing query parameter Theme_Id after first time run doesn't make query longer - is caching also reason for this?)

Comment: You can find out for sure by seeing if clearing the cache with `CHECKPOINT; DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` repeatedly makes the problem recur. Obviously a test best done on a development server!

Comment: @Martin - we used DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS command when posted statistics

Comment: @Martin, we repeated command several times with DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS and problem recurred. Execution average time was 15 seconds.

Comment: And in your query that you posted does changing the two `inner join` s to `inner hash join` make things better or worse?

Comment: @Martin, inner hash join make things better. It is a good advice! Also the execution plan dramatically changed. And now with DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS average time of execution is about 2-3 seconds. So we have two question more: 1. if there are many ways to make the query more faster :). 2. How can we in linq to entities force using inner hash join instead of simple join ?

Comment: The ideal solution would be to get SQL Server to use the plan automatically. Do you have up-to-date statistics on these tables? If not maybe updating these will get it to choose the plan. Failing that you might need to use a plan guide.

Comment: @Martin, what do you mean about table statistics. We have maintenance plans, that regular rebuild all indexes on our tables. Or do we have to do smth else?

Comment: @mmcteam-com-ua By default you won't need to do anything. Auto create statistics and auto update statistics should be turned on. It's only if these are turned off you will need to do anything but you could try `sp_updatestats` just to be sure.

Comment: @Martin, so current reason of our problem is in fact that sql automatically create not the best execution plan? And we have to figure out how get automatically plan that we force with writing inner hash join instead of inner join ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [Martin's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/513811/martin) advices in comments to question, the answer is in understanding how SQL Server build the execution plans and counting disk reads operation needed to first query run.

In our particular situation, forced `inner hash join` instead of `inner join` give to us result as we expected and different execution plan that SQL choose by default.

Answer (score 0):

The query is quite hairy, but It looks like you are missing an index on `Mention.Theme_ID`?

Sql server is having problem because a lot of `<>` are used, meaning that it cannot use an index and must fetch everything and then sort it out.

Comment: We have index on Mention.Theme_Id (this field is in an Index named Big_Index) - you can see it on execution plan. About <> - you can see from execution plan also that 99% takes index seeking. So sql uses index. And index seeking the only operation that takes time for this query.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It would be interesting to see the amount of logical reads for each table when the query executes.

Comment: Edited post - added link to image with index seek performance information.

Comment: we added a comment with the amount of logical reads for each table